# How to call a stored procedure with parameter from dataimporthandler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Hi can anybody tell me how to call a stored procedure with parameter in db-config.xml file.

I have a stored procedure which takes **date time** as a parameter and it returns me the rows which are created or modified after the specified parameter.

While trying to call that stored procedure from dataimporthandler i am not getting success.

My db-config.xml is like below

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-1" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://DataBaseURL;databaseName=DBtest" user="sa" password="MyPassword" readOnly="True" />
<document>
    <entity dataSource="ds-1" name="JobSeekerDetails" query="exec [SP_GetAllJobSeekerDetails] '${dih.last_index_time}'"
            deltaImportQuery="exec [SP_GetAllJobSeekerDetails] '${dih.last_index_time}'"
            deltaQuery="exec [SP_GetAllJobSeekerDetails] '${dih.last_index_time}'">

        <field column="FName" name="FName" />
        <field column="LName" name="LName" />
        <field column="Exp_year" name="Exp_year" />
        <field column="Exp_Month" name="Exp_Month" />
        <field column="INDUSTRY" name="INDUSTRY" />         
        <field column="DESIREDPOSITION" name="DESIREDPOSITION" />
        <field column="ROLE_NAME" name="ROLE_NAME" />
        <field column="PHONE_NUMBER" name="PHONE_NUMBER" />
        <field column="COUNTRY_NAME" name="COUNTRY_NAME" />
        <field column="STATE_NAME" name="STATE_NAME" />
        <field column="CITY_NAME" name="CITY_NAME" />
        <field column="POSTAL_CODE" name="POSTAL_CODE" />

    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Please help me to find out where i am doing mistakes.

Also i have tried without using **exec** key word inside query parameter.

Thanks in advance.